# POSIX regex to match a message

Tags: c, regex, posix

I'm using the POSIX C regex's. I need a regex which will match several fields out of a message. It must also reject any message that does not match the format. The message fomat is:

String1|Integer1|String2|String3|Integer2|...IntegerN`

The '|' character is used as the delimiter between the fields. The final integers are a list with 0 or more items. Any field may be blank (no space, no hidden character between the delimiters).

Basically I just want to be able to pull out the fields separately.

So far I have:

```
.*|[0-9]3|.*|.*|([0-9]3|)50[\`]
```

I wrote this without any escape characters for clarity. I also added the number of items each field can contain. And I forgot the end of message character.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have a problem? or just a requirements statement?

Comment: I'm just starting to use it now so I wanted to get a correct answer from an experienced user so I know when my understanding is correct.

I also thought I might get an opinion on whether this is the correct tool for this job.

Comment: "Branches" match my delimiters, is that a problem?

Comment: not really. all regex engines allow for escaping the operator chars (usually by prefixing a `\`).

Comment: It'd help if you posted the regular expressions you've tried. I've only every used libpcre, but, you could probably be experimenting using some online tester, syntax should come out almost the same. You'll have to escape the `|` characters like `\|` since `|` has a special meaning in a regex.

Comment: @macattack ok, thanks. I'm looking for something like "%s|%d|%s|%s|(%d|)`" if that helps, where the term in brackets can be missing, or repeated many times.

Comment: collapsar gave a good answer which sounds like what you want. You should really start testing pieces of your regex on strings it'll have to match and expand it as you see each part of it is working. Online tools are very helpful in understanding your regex: http://www.debuggex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
^([^|]+)\|([[:digit:]]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)((\|[[:digit:]]+)*)$
```

in your favorite regex engine. if there are constraints on the nature of your `String` items, it is advisable to incorporate them into the pattern for more reliable error detection. the individual portions are available as capture groups 1 through 5, where #5 contains all final integers. i do not know of a regex engine that would auto-segment a partial pattern but you should be able to use a method similar to perl's `split(/\|/, $_)` to this end.

Comment: Thanks @collapsar  

I don't think I specified the problem 100% correctly but that should give me a good place to start.